# Bootstrap position element to container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/awyory2a/

It's a full width image with a bootstrap container ontop that contains a header.

I have two divs positioned at the bottom centered and skewed to create a cut out triangle showing the image below.

My simple question is can I position the divs so the triangle cut out appears below the header so it is fixed below
the left side of the bootstrap container, like in the image attached.[image]

```
.header {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
}
.bar {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.bar-left {
    transform: skewX(-60deg);
    left: 50%;
}
.bar-right {
    transform: skewX(60deg);
    right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Does the triangle need to have the background image in it? The way you are doing this seems weird. Check out this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: `right: 50%;` can you use absolue values?

Comment: floor - the whole idea is the triangle is like a cut out with the image behind it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not so easy. But there is a solution: using `clip-path` CSS property:

```
clip-path: polygon(15px 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 155px 80%, 85px 90%, 15px 80%);
```

The trick here is to have two blocks with the same background image, so that one block is outside container and another one — inside (and clipped). Just make sure that image is wide enough to be positioned properly as a background.

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/tonystar/pen/JdOBvo)

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1):

How about setting your `bar-left` and `bar-right` positions to :

```
.bar-left{
    transform: skewX(-60deg);
    left: 20%;
}

.bar-right{
    transform: skewX(60deg);
    right: 80%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ujhyek2/)

**Update:**
If you want to make it more responsive, so when you resize your browser it doesn't move.

Do it like this instead:

```
.bar-left{
    transform: skewX(-50deg);
    left: 65px;
}

.bar-right{
    transform: skewX(50deg);
    right: calc(100% - 65px);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kcxck1m/11/)

Answer (score -1):

What if you just change the background color of the divs with the class '.bar' from gray to white (or any desired color to match the background of the parent element)? This will give the illusion that the triangle is outside the header.

Here is a screenshot I took to your jsfiddle with my suggestion:
[image]

I hope this helps